# Modeling parallel operations in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm creating a database model for a capacity planning tool for manufacturing.  I'd like to be able to define the amount of hours of capacity by day and by workstation.  Each project will have a list of tasks that will create demand against these workstations by day.  I want to create an algorithm that will back-schedule the tasks after the last one is given a end date.

Because of the nature of the manufacturing process, some tasks are parallel with others.  We can have 3 or more activities parallel.  I need a way to define which tasks are parallel with others.

MySQL has a "m has n" relationship in their EER editor.  Is this the right way to model this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need define what activity are in parallel. As long you define `Begin Date` and `End Date` for each task, you can calculate what activity are in parallel with each other.

So if you have the date range for a single activity you can calculate what other activity are in parallel by:

```
SELECT activity.*
FROM activity
WHERE activity.begin_date < @this_activity_end_date
  AND activity.end_date > @this_activity_begin_date
```

Comment: The dates are dynamic.  The end user will enter the due date on the last operation, and the rest of the dates are calculated based on the duration of the predecessors

Comment: Then you have a parent-child relationship, but that is different to the parallel question. You can solve that with triggers or creating a View.